# Mapping a Vim command followed by a replacement

Tags: vim

I'm using the following the wrap the current paragraph and then remove the double spaces:

```
nnoremap Q gqap :s/  / /g<cr>
```

But when I execute it I  get pattern no found, which is strange since it works if I do it separately: `:s/  / /g` + `Enter`

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is it possible that it is not evaluating the gqap because nnoremap is non-recursive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping itself looks fine; I guess the problem is that `:s` only works on the *current* line, whereas after reformatting, the text may be distributed across multiple lines. You can fix that by addressing the last changed range (`:'[,']`) for `:substitute`. As there aren't necessarily multiple spaces (better matched by `\+` to also match more than 2), you can suppress the error with the `/e` flag:

```
:nnoremap Q gqap:'[,']s/ \+/ /ge<cr>
```